# Picture element: do I need to set the full path in every scrset attribute?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, picture-element

Responsive images, the use-cases and the new HTML5 `picture` element are explained quite well in [this article](https://dev.opera.com/articles/responsive-images/).

**Update**: To be more specific, I mean with responsive images, resized images for different devices. Less image weight, so [faster loading sites](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2015/05/12/hero-image-custom-metrics/).
Up to [72% less weight](http://timkadlec.com/2013/06/why-we-need-responsive-images/).

The shown Examples are just filenames (no path), in practice it will be more verbose like:

```
<picture>
<source
    media="(min-width: 1280px)"
    sizes="50vw"
    srcset="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-200.webp 200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-400.webp 400w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-800.webp 800w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-1200.webp 1200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-1600.webp 1600w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-2000.webp 2000w"
    type="image/webp">
<source
    sizes="(min-width: 640px) 60vw, 100vw"
    srcset="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-200.webp 200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-400.webp 400w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-800.webp 800w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-1200.webp 1200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-1600.webp 1600w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-2000.webp 2000w"
    type="image/webp">
<source
    media="(min-width: 1280px)"
    sizes="50vw"
    srcset="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-200.jpg 200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-400.jpg 400w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-800.jpg 800w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-1200.jpg 1200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-1600.jpg 1800w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-fullshot-2000.jpg 2000w">
<img
    src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-400.jpg" alt="The Oslo Opera House"
    sizes="(min-width: 640px) 60vw, 100vw"
    srcset="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-200.jpg 200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-400.jpg 400w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-800.jpg 800w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-1200.jpg 1200w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-1600.jpg 1600w,
            wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-2000.jpg 2000w">
</picture>
```

Setting the full path every time seems akward.

I prefer this:

```
<picture pathset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/">
<source
    media="(min-width: 1280px)"
    sizes="50vw"
    srcset="opera-fullshot-200.webp 200w,
            opera-fullshot-400.webp 400w,
            opera-fullshot-800.webp 800w,
            opera-fullshot-1200.webp 1200w,
            opera-fullshot-1600.webp 1600w,
            opera-fullshot-2000.webp 2000w"
    type="image/webp">
<source
    sizes="(min-width: 640px) 60vw, 100vw"
    srcset="opera-closeup-200.webp 200w,
            opera-closeup-400.webp 400w,
            opera-closeup-800.webp 800w,
            opera-closeup-1200.webp 1200w,
            opera-closeup-1600.webp 1600w,
            opera-closeup-2000.webp 2000w"
    type="image/webp">
<source
    media="(min-width: 1280px)"
    sizes="50vw"
    srcset="opera-fullshot-200.jpg 200w,
            opera-fullshot-400.jpg 400w,
            opera-fullshot-800.jpg 800w,
            opera-fullshot-1200.jpg 1200w,
            opera-fullshot-1600.jpg 1800w,
            opera-fullshot-2000.jpg 2000w">
<img
    src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/opera-closeup-400.jpg" alt="The Oslo Opera House"
    sizes="(min-width: 640px) 60vw, 100vw"
    srcset="opera-closeup-200.jpg 200w,
            opera-closeup-400.jpg 400w,
            opera-closeup-800.jpg 800w,
            opera-closeup-1200.jpg 1200w,
            opera-closeup-1600.jpg 1600w,
            opera-closeup-2000.jpg 2000w">
</picture>
```

> BTW for readability and programming logic I prefer the responsive
>   stuff in the path not in filename. The you can do this
>
> ```
> <picture pathset=/pathtoimages/>
>  <source fileset=opera-fullshot.webp
>       sizes="(min-width: 640px) 60vw, 100vw"
> ...
>     srcset="200w/ 200w,
>             800w/ 800w,
>             1200w/ 1200w,
>             1600w/ 1600w,">
> ...
> <source fileset=opera-closeup.webp
> ...
>     srcset="200w/ 200w,
>             800w/ 800w,
>             1200w/ 1200w,
>             1600w/ 1600w,">
> </picture>
> ```
>
> If you drop support for a certain width, just delete the directory.

But the main issue, we need quite a lot of code for 1 image.

So, to limit that (without any JS solution):

Can I set something like a **pathsrc** attribute or scoped **base** element?

Comment: The support for the picture element is so terrible that I wouldn't recommend using [it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture).

Comment: [50% is not terrible](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture) IMHO

Comment: @persijn the picture fill poly fill covers nearly every browser in use.

Comment: Unfortunately the specs can save maybe up  to 72% in image-weight, it adds 2000% HTML (img tag) weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

It is an obvious idea to use a template syntax in srcset. In fact it was part of the [earliest srcset draft](http://junkyard.damowmow.com/506). However, URLs can and do contain anything, and don't always map to a template (e.g. generated GUIDs for different images), so it didn't work.

In theory you could use XHTML and `xml:base`. In practice, you don't use XHTML, and `xml:base` support is being [removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=903372) [from](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/ZvArHAXyAHM/ftybb0waCKYJ) browsers.

I would recommend not worrying so much about the repetition, just make sure you use gzip.

Comment: Thx. gzip will help. XML compresses fine to, still it has scaling issues.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer this is not an solution to your question. But a solution for responsive images

#### SVG

The <svg> element is [highly supported.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg)

There is an example of a responsive svg image:

```css
circle {
  fill: firebrick;
}
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="DarkOrange" />
  <rect x="40" y="40" width="50" height="50" fill="SeaGreen" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" />
</svg>
```

Press the **<kbd>run code snippet</kbd>** and then <kbd>Full page</kbd> to test it out.

#### CSS

Or you can simple use an image that scales down properly:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4rY4PlSCy48/maxresdefault.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, my main concern: saving bandwith, no 1920px pics for phones.

Comment: Then maybe its better with a @media css and downloading the pictures on. There should be some good articles on how to optimize sites and pictures for phones.